# Unexpected result in PHP for collecting data from MS Access MDB

Tags: php

I have the following coding but the criteria in WHERE clause does not work...

```
<?php 
$con = odbc_connect("attend", "", "123");
 if ($con) {
        $sql = "
            select 
                accessrec.eid,
                employee.fullname,
                Format(CDate(Left(accessrec.accessdate,4) & '/' & Mid(accessrec.accessdate,5,2) & '/' & Right(accessrec.accessdate,2)),'dd/mm/yyyy') as accessdate, 
                iif(len(trim(AccessRec.accesstime))>5,left(AccessRec.accesstime,2) & ':' & mid(AccessRec.accesstime,3,2) & ':' & right(AccessRec.accesstime,2),left(AccessRec.accesstime,1) & ':' & mid(AccessRec.accesstime,2,2) & ':' & right(AccessRec.accesstime,2)) as accesstime 
            from accessRec 
            left join employee on accessrec.eid = employee.eid 
            WHERE (accessdate >=#01/01/2018# AND employee.fullname='Leung Ka Hei-MIS') 
            ORDER BY accessdate ASC, accesstime ASC
        ";
    $result = odbc_exec($con, $sql);
}
?>
```

Filtering does not work on WHERE clause, so it will display all records instead...

Comment: Sorry, Tatranskymedved for misleading you...

Comment: I understand what is the problem now, the data in the field accessdate is an integer and no matter what I have to change the data type in WHERE clause, I cannot get the result as expected, because when I put #01/01/2018#  system unable to compare it.  The data stored as an integer in accessate as below;
20090726
20090727
20180101
20180102